# What is the meaning of "Take medicine with meal"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I am not a native English speaker. When I see medicines with label stating "Take this with a meal" what does it actually mean?

1. Before starting the meal
2. After finishing the meal
3. In between
4. Any of the above.

Comment: is this ELL  question?

Comment: If you take the medicine and immediately begin eating, you should have no problem. But there is always the possibility that after you took the medicine some unexpected interruption might occur, leaving you with the undesirable result of having medicine that you are supposed to take with a meal but instead is sitting in your otherwise empty stomach. So your best bet is to eat at least some of your meal before taking the medicine. Still, the technical answer to your question is "(4) Any of the above"—as long as you take the medicine in very close proximity to the meal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what it actually means. Take it **while** eating a meal, or after you have already started eating the meal. The idea is not to take it on an empty stomach. (Note this is not medical advice and you should consult your doctor if you have questions about the prescription or nonprescription medicine.)

Some medicines may upset an empty stomach. Some medicines may work too quickly if taken on an empty stomach. For the same reason, doctors may prescribe some medicines to be taken on an empty stomach.

Some medicines interfere with the work of other medicines, and so they shouldn't be taken within two hours of each other.

Comment: Appreciate the help. :)